# Probability notation: is it better to write P[{number of heads}] or P[number of heads]

Tags: probability, notation

In a probability lecture, the prof was doing a conditional probability question (given a fair and unfair coin with probability $p_1$, $p_2$, what is the probability of getting $k$ heads in $n$ tosses), in which he writes:

P[number of heads = $k$|fair coin is chosen]

= P[number of heads  = $k$ $\cap$ fair coin is chosen}\P[fair coin is chosen]

---

Would it be better to write:

P[{number of heads = $k$}] instead of  P[number of heads = $k$] ?

and

P[{number of heads = $k$|fair coin is chosen}] instead of  P[number of heads = $k$|fair coin is chosen]?

Comment: I would personally describe the number of heads as a random variable, say for example $H$, and describe the event that a fair coin is chosen as an event and name it something like $F$.  We can then write it as $P(H=k~\mid~F)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, it would be best practice not to mix words into symbols.   It is often done, because it conveys the meaning to students and communication is a key to teaching.

Well, anyway, that aside you do have the idea that events are sets of outcomes.

It is acceptable to use a random variable notation --either of $X=x$ or $\{X=x\}$, or such-- to represent the event "the event for the count of heads equals $x$".   Mostly because we don't like writing a full set builder notation, such as $\{\omega\in \Omega: X(\omega)=x\}$,  over and over when the convenient shorthand *will suffice*.   It is understood that $X=x$ describes a set of outcomes, but sometimes using $\{X=x\}$ makes this clearer, but which abreviation you use is a style choice.

Likewise we can use $F$ for "the event the fair coin is choosen".   However, this is the *name* of an event, so there is never any urge to wrap it in brackets.

Thus $\mathsf P(X=x\mid F)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X=x, F)}{\mathsf P(F)}$, and  $\mathsf P(\{X=x\}\mid F) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(\{X=x\}\cap F)}{\mathsf P(F)}$ are equally acceptable.

---

So... if you *must* use words, there is no *need* to wrap them in brackets.   Just use the words.   Though I would *not* say there was anything wrong with parenthesising a phrase.

$\mathsf P(\{{\small\text{number of heads is }x}\}\mid \{{\small\text{fair coin is used}}\})=\dfrac{\mathsf P(\{{\small\text{number of heads is }x}\}\cap \{{\small\text{fair coin is used}}\})}{\mathsf P(\{{\small\text{fair coin is used}}\})}$

Comment: I wrote my dissertation for the International Baccalaureate over this topic. It’s entitled “How has the language of set theory facilitated mathematics in probability theory?” and it covers: concepts, jargon and definitions; visuals; and notation and calculation. I liked your answer very much.